# Azure B2C login fails if you wait 15 mins

Tags: .net, azure-ad-msal

I've used the Azure sample:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C

to connect to my b2c instance.

If you press the sign in button, then get transferred to b2c, and wait 15 minutes before entering your valid credentials, you get the error: Correlation Failed.

[image]

The, once you get this then try to log in again, you find out that your already logged in.

Please can someone help? Thank you.
I've also raised an issue with the sample:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/572

Answer (score 0):

When accessing your application, you started an http session with your application server. The application redirected you to SSO login. After 15min your session with the application server is timed out, so when you log in and are redirected back to the application this error happens.

When you reload a new session is created and - as you are successfully authenticated with SSO - you are logged in.

What you can do: Extend the session duration on your application server to a duration you are happy with or handle that session loss in your application.